# StacMan - .NET client for Stack Exchange API v2

Tags: library, api-v2, c#, .net

### Features

- Supports [**all** Stack Exchange API V2 methods](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) through version 2.1
- **Easy to use**: one-to-one mapping between StacMan and API methods/params
- **Async is easy**: methods return [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) so they're [ready for C# 5's `await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh533273)
- Adheres to the [API's throttling rules](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)

### Supported Frameworks

- **StacMan 0.4.0.0 or earlier**: .NET 4.0
- **StacMan 1.0.0.0 or later**: .NET 4.5

### Get StacMan

[StacMan is available on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/StacMan):

```
PM> Install-Package StacMan
```

### Example Usage

```
using StackExchange.StacMan;
...
var client = new StacManClient(key: "my-app-key", version: "2.1");
```

**Synchronous**

```
var response = client.Questions.GetAll("stackoverflow",
    page: 1,
    pagesize: 10,
    sort: Questions.AllSort.Creation,
    order: Order.Desc,
    filter: "!mDO35lQRaz").Result;

foreach (var question in response.Data.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
}
```

**Asynchronous**

```
var task = client.Questions.GetAll("stackoverflow",
    page: 1,
    pagesize: 10,
    sort: Questions.AllSort.Creation,
    order: Order.Desc,
    filter: "!mDO35lQRaz");

task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        foreach (var user in t.Result.Data.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
        }
    });
```

**Asynchronous (C# 5)**

```
var response = await client.Questions.GetAll("stackoverflow",
    page: 1,
    pagesize: 10,
    sort: Questions.AllSort.Creation,
    order: Order.Desc,
    filter: "!mDO35lQRaz");

foreach (var user in response.Data.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Title);
}
```

### Filters

StacMan supports the Stack Exhchange API's concept of [filters](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), which allow applications to specify which fields are included/excluded in the API response.

When a field is excluded, the property returned by StacMan corresponding to the excluded field assumes the *default value* of the type. For example, when the "default" filter is used, the `AnswerCount` property of the User object returned by StacMan will be 0, since `user.answer_count` is not included by the "default" filter.

Comment: Any support for WinRT?

Comment: Any final solution and full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using C# for the first time.

When I compile the StacMan source under the v3.5 framework I get this error:

> Error 2   Default parameter specifiers are not permitted   StacManClient.SuggestedEditMethods.cs

From what I have read, it seems that this error occurs when not using the .NET framework v4 for compiling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, you need to use at least C# 4 (the version in which optional parameters were added).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I am not able to install that package. I'll get this error:

```
PM> Install-Package StacMan
"StacMan 1.0.1.0" wurde erfolgreich installiert.
"StacMan 1.0.1.0" wurde erfolgreich deinstalliert.
Installationsfehler. Rollback wird ausgeführt...
Install-Package : Das Paket "StacMan 1.0.1.0" konnte nicht installiert werden. Sie versuchen, dieses Paket in ein Projekt zu installi
eren, das sich auf ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" bezieht, das Paket enthält jedoch keine Assemblyverweise, die mit dies
em Framework kompatibel sind. Wenden Sie sich an den Paketersteller, um weitere Informationen zu erhalten.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  StacMan
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

And here is the output for the full profile:

```
Paket-Manager-Konsolenhost, Version 2.2.40116.9051

Geben Sie "get-help NuGet" ein, um alle verfügbaren NuGet-Befehle anzuzeigen.

PM> Install-Package StacMan
"StacMan 1.0.1.0" wurde erfolgreich installiert.
"StacMan 1.0.1.0" wurde erfolgreich deinstalliert.
Installationsfehler. Rollback wird ausgeführt...
Install-Package : Das Paket "StacMan 1.0.1.0" konnte nicht installiert werden. Sie versuchen, dieses Paket in ein Projekt zu installi
eren, das sich auf ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" bezieht, das Paket enthält jedoch keine Assemblyverweise oder Inhaltsdateien, die mit
 diesem Framework kompatibel sind. Wenden Sie sich an den Paketersteller, um weitere Informationen zu erhalten.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  StacMan
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Is the project you are trying to install the package into targeting .Net 4.0 Client Profile or the full .Net 4.0 Framework? Based off this error, StackMan requires the project you're installing it on to target .Net 4.0 Framework, not the Client profile.

Comment: I tried both profiles none of them worked. That is very confusing. By the way I never used nuget before.

Comment: I just downloaded the package and took a look at it.  The package requires .Net 4.5.  The last nuget package that supports .Net 4.0 is version 0.4. I'm not sure how stable it is, but you could install it if you want to.  To install it, run this command in the Package Manager:
`Install-Package StacMan -Version 0.4.0.0`

Comment: Oh sh... Well now it works for me too. I changed it to .net 4.5. There should be a note about that.

Comment: I agree.  Hopefully its stable now.

Comment: I added a note about supported frameworks to the OP.