# "error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"

Tags: support, api, comments, voting

I developed an application, user can give vote down or up to question or comments but when I send the request to the API of the stackexchenge the response it is not true and this back to me error number 500 
what is wrong? more over I am passing Access_token by write access.

```
{"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}
```

I am using the [StacMan](https://stackapps.com/questions/3411/stacman-net-client-for-stack-exchange-api-v2) library:

```
public StacManClient _StacManClient = new StacManClient(key: "my_key", version: "2.2");

var responsedownvote = _StacManClient.Questions.downvote(SiteSearch, id: new List<int> { CommentId }, access_token: TokenAccess, filter: "", preview: true).Result;

var responseupvote= _StacManClient.Questions.upvote(SiteSearch, id: new List<int> { CommentId }, access_token: TokenAccess, filter: "", preview: true).Result;
```

Comment: You need to provide a recipe for duplicating the problem.

Comment: thanks @BrockAdam I edited and add some more code if you need to know more I will be glad to know :)