# How to get my StackOverFlow API Key

Tags: support, api, .net

I used to login in StackOverFlow site using my Gmail Id/password.How I will get my StackOverFlow API key? I require that key to fire a StackExchage API which requires authentication.

Also, could anybody provide an example in .NET for posting question in StackOverFlow using APIs? I think StackExchange APIs 2.0 allows posting from outside.I have checked few .NET wrapper libraries for StackExchange 2.0 APIs, but all of them implemented only GET APIs.Is there any library that implemented .NET wrapper methods for POST with authentication key?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: The [*StacMan* library](http://stackapps.com/q/3411/7653) claims to support all api-v2.1 methods -- which include write and edit of comments.  You should be able to take those write examples and modify them for api-v2.2 Q&A posting (method's the same, only the data changes).